# Custom Editor For

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Assume we have a view that accepts BigModel class as a model:

```
class BigModel
{
    public int SimpleValue{get;set;}
    public SmallModel ComplexValue{get;set;}
}
class SmallModel
{
    public string AnotherSimpleValue{get;set;}
}
```

The view have an EditorFor for `SimpleValue` and a partial view that accepts `SmallModel`
class as a model. How do I make this partial view work as some kind of EditorFor for an instance of `SmallModel`.

My goal is to achieve at the end of all editings a fully configured instance of `BigModel` in my controller when user submits the form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `EditorTemplate`. In your relevant `Views` folder, create a directory called `EditorTemplates` and in it a `.cshtml` file with the same name as your class. MVC will automatically look there when you call

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.BigModel)
```

For more information about Editor/Display templates, see this [link](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/).